# rethinkdb cluster, what if some of servers are down?

Tags: rethinkdb

I have 5 servers. On my first "primary" I have in config:

```
join=ip2:port
join=ip3:port
join=ip4:port
join=ip5:port
```

I am connection to rethinkdb via proxy:

```
proxy --join ip1:port --join ip2:port
```

**When I stop rethinkdb on ip1 everything stops**. I do not know how to solve this. Rethinkdb docs are not complete. Do I have to define this joins in every config?

UPDATE
In fact when I stop any server in cluster my app crash! I am getting in webui something like "Table db.table is available for outdated reads, but not up-to-date reads or writes."

Except table shards I do not see point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you usually want every node to know the address of every other node so that they can connect to each other if any subset of the nodes is down.

Comment: yes well I am not sure about this. How do you know? I have stopped my ip2 server and it says something like "table is available for outdated reads only" and of course app is not working!

Comment: There are two separate things: one is that your servers need to be able to reach each other, and the other is that you need to be able to reach the master for a shard in order to do writes or up-to-date reads.  If your problem is that your servers can't reach each other, you can fix that by adding the correct join lines to each config.  If your problem is that the master for the shard is permanently unavailable, then probably automatic failover isn't working.  You can read about that at https://rethinkdb.com/docs/failover/, but the gist is that you need at least 3 replicas.